Analyzing Anomalies with GCP Timeseries Insights API
Based on the tutorial from the GCP Timeseries Insights API documentation (https://cloud.google.com/timeseries-insights/docs/tutorial), I tried to create a dataset with my JSON to identify its anomalies:
{
  "name": "jobs_table",
  "dataNames": [
    "user_email",
    "job_id"
  ],
  "dataSources": [
    {
      "uri": "gs://timeseries-teste/jobs.json"
    }
  ]
}

However, when queried, the response only returns the dataset name without the anomaly details:
{
  "detectionTime": "2024-10-01T00:00:00Z", 
  "numReturnedSlices": 5, 
  "slicingParams": {
    "dimensionNames": ["job_id"]
  },
  "timeseriesParams": {
    "forecastHistory": "1209600s",  
    "granularity": "86400s"       
  },
  "forecastParams": {
    "noiseThreshold": 100.0       
  }
}

Return:
{
  "name": "projects/*project_id*/datasets/jobs_table"
}

